# jQuery post of array to PHP returns a string on server side... why?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, post

Given the following table... I am taking the value of each cell and appending to a data array...

```
    <table id="ProductTable" width="1200">
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>SLOTP10</td>
            <td>Some Description</td>
            <td>Some Qty</td>
            <td>Some Price</td>
            <td>Some Extended Total</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    </table>

// FORM ELEMENTS ARE NOT SHOWN BUT THIS IS VALID
var data = $("#wbmasonorder").serializeArray(); 
var key = -1;
var products = [];      

$('#ProductTable tbody tr td').each(function(index,element) {
    if (index % 5 == 0) {
        key++;
        products[key]=[];
    }
    products[key].push($(this).html());
});
data.push({
    name: 'products',
    value: products
});
console.log(data);

$.post(url,data);
```

When I log the data, the value of the node displays as an array in the console, but when I post it, the value of $_POST['products'] is a comma separated string... not an array

Comment: Perhaps you need to name it `name: 'products[]'` instead? http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: It is not a form element, it is a table whos cells will be appended to data from the form values

Comment: If you post it to a PHP script, you need to treat it like form elements.

Comment: That is not true, but thanks for your input

Comment: You might try posting the code that's actually posting the data to your PHP script.

Comment: its a jquery post, just like any other... $.post(url,data);

Comment: Then it should be named like an array, as I said. Did you *try* my suggestion?

Comment: oh you are saying to name the node  "products[]"... I was not following you

Comment: That still did not work I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the post from just posting the data array, to posting an object containing the data array and the products separately

Example...

```
$.post(url, {data: data, products: products });
```

Instead of...

```
$.post(url, data);
```

Working correctly now and I'm unsure as to why it failed to retain array form when being appended to the data array, but its working so case closed.

Thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 0):

[PHP convention is to name POSTed variables with `[]` at the end client-side, if they're to be treated like arrays server-side](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays). Try the following change to your JavaScript:

```
data.push({
    name: 'products[]',
    value: products
});
```

Comment: This is the actual return of echo $_POST['products'];

"MAG71200 ,Abracadabra Bright White Copy Paper, 5000/CT 20 lb., 97 bright 8 1/2" x 11" letter ,1,27.99,27.99"

Comment: I'm going to try to just make the whole thing an object containing products and the data array

Comment: also whether the node is named with the [] or not, does not matter, though it may be convention

Answer (score 0):

You are serializing the js array which basically turns the array to a string. You need to unserialize the string back to an array once received in php.

You might want to look into JSON arrays / strings.

Comment: FYI... `.serializeArray` performs a little bit differently than `.serialize()` and it is an array... you might want to look into the difference between the 2

Comment: @zgr024 If you want us to help you, you might try to be a little less condescending.

Comment: that was my comment, not @Blazemonger. However, how do I know you level of knowledge? Your here asking for help.

Comment: I'm asking a specific question about why an array is becoming a string... and your answer is incorrect in the fact that it `serializeArray` does not turn it into text... how am I being more condescending than anyone else

Comment: "How can I pass this as an array?"... "FYI... .serializeArray performs a little bit differently than .serialize() and it is an array..." Doesn't make sense.

Comment: its an array in JavaScript, and then not in PHP... is that more clear?

Comment: "The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects, ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types:"

Comment: The array is still an array none the less in javascript, and placing it a parent array should not change it to text when posted